# How to show a location with respect to my current location?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, location, compass-geolocation

I have a lat and longitude of my friend's location also my current location.
I want to show the position of my friend with respect to my location, just like a compass - in an iPhone app.
I know the function didUpdateHeading -

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
NSLog(@"New magnetic heading: %f", newHeading.magneticHeading);
NSLog(@"New true heading: %f", newHeading.trueHeading);
}
```

I am not getting an idea about how to do this, Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

If nobody else provides a better solution here is how to do it:

Your point is A, your friend point is B, and the common point is whatever 0,0 , a common reference : C

Use [distanceFromLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/distanceFromLocation%3a)  function.

With that point you will know the 3 triangle side.
Now go to wikipedia or back to 6th class school how to calculate the angles on triangle if you have the side values.

You need 1 of the angle.

I am lazy to to search and write a ready for copy-paste code, because I know you will not up-vote this either :)